# update problems 18.10

Tags: updates

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8118 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-proposed InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8118:
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8118:
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8118:
Err:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease
  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8118 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8118:
```

Comment: There is no internet connection.

Comment: @Pilot6 Aaacctually that's not so true, that's indicative of a proxy being configured not an Internet connection issue (see that it's trying to reach a local IP/port combo first, that suggests a proxy)

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8118:

This suggests you have some type of proxy configured.  That proxy is offline and not able to be reached, and since `apt` is configured to go through that proxy, which is offline, you can't download packages.

You would need to dig into your `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*` settings files to see where the proxy is being defined and try deactivating the proxy requirement; if it still doesn't work then you need to go figure out whether you must have that proxy running in order to get access to the Internet at large for updates, Internet traffic, etc.